# Type checking strings instead of using instanceof

Tags: node.js, typescript, tcp, typescript-typings, tsc

Say I have a library that does TCP and the response could be vary, some responses representing errors.

It doesn't make much sense to use an Error object because that is expensive, but also the stack trace doesn't have anything to do with the original request since the error, it were to occur, would occur asynchronously.

So the best thing I can think of is a simple string, something like:

```
const makeRequest = function(err, result){

    if(err && err.code === 'Request timeout'){

    }

    if(err && err.code === 'Unauthorized'){

    }
};
```

How can I allow users to type check the string with TypeScript?

Answer (score 2):

You can use string literal strings to offer type checking for the error codes (and also good code completion support for the error codes).

```
interface CustomError {
    code:'Request timeout' | 'Unauthorized'
}

const makeRequest = function(err : CustomError | null, result : any){
    if(err && err.code === 'Not an error'){ // This would be an error

    }
    if(err && err.code === 'Request timeout'){

    }

    if(err && err.code === 'Unauthorized'){

    }
};
```

If each type of error has extra information you want to provide you could also combine string literal types with a discriminated union:

```
interface TimoutoutError {
    code: 'Request timeout'
    time: number;
}

interface UnauthorizedError {
    code: 'Unauthorized'
    user: string;
}

type CustomError = TimoutoutError | UnauthorizedError;

const makeRequest = function (err: CustomError | null, result: any) {
    if (err && err.code === 'Not an error') { // This would be an error

    }
    if (err && err.code === 'Request timeout') {
        err.time; // err is TimoutoutError
    }

    if (err && err.code === 'Unauthorized') {
        err.user // err is UnauthorizedError
    }
};
```